# google visualization date format in getValue

Tags: google-visualization

Where do I set the data format when displaying data from a dataTable? The code below is not working.

```
a.getDataTable().getValue(0, 2, {pattern: "dd-MM-yyy"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you must format the data table values.
you can use one of Google's [formatters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters), in this case the [DateFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat) class.

once the data table has been loaded with data,
use the formatter to format the data.

```
// create date formatter
var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
  pattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
});

// format data table column index 2
formatDate.format(dataTable, 2);
```

then when displaying data from the data table,
use the `getFormattedValue` method, to display the formatted value...

```
dataTable.getFormattedValue(0, 2);
```